# Communicate between rails and phoenix using exq and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phoenix-framework, sidekiq, exq

I am trying to add bridge between Rails and Phoenix framework to communicate. So far I can enqueue jobs in rails and those are picked up by Exq in phoenix framework.

```
Sidekiq::Client.push({"queue" => "elixir_queue", "class" => "ElixirQueue", "args" => ["foo"]})
```

But I am having issue enqueueing job from Elixir for rails to pick up. I tried this and it enqueues job

```
Exq.enqueue(Exq, "rails_queue", 'RailsQueueJob' , ["Hello there rails"],  max_retries: 0)
```

but Sidekiq on rails side throws error saying `"error_message\":\"undefined method jid=' for #< RailsQueueJob:0x00007fe599dfda50>`. There happens to be no documentation for this. How can I Enqueue from elixir and let Sidekiq pick up the job.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that means that you need to steak to Sidekiq Job Format.
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Job-Format
I.e. Sidekiq is trying to fetch jid out of the RailsQueueJob - you need to define it by yourself I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rails issue. Explained here
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3073

Comment: I know but I want ActiveJob, they are so simple to use

Comment: The Sidekiq API is easy to use too!